# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoWriteConcernError and ValidationError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

My code is showing the following MongoWriteError once I open it, and after some time, then the ValidationError when I add data to my to-do list application.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path username is required.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern named 'majority/todolistDB'
```

This is the `itemsSchema` part:

```
  var itemsSchema = new Schema({
  username:  {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

This saved me from the MongoWriteError but it tends to work for a while.

This is the server part:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://cluster0-hjbfj.mongodb.net/test? 
  retryWrites=true&w=majority/todolistDB", {
  dbName: 'todolistDB',
  user: 'USERNAME',
  pass: 'PASSWORD',
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
   })
 .then(() => {
 console.log("MongoDB Connected");
 })
  .catch((error) => {
 assert.isNotOk(error,'Promise error');
  });
```

...

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){


 const itemName = req.body.newItem;
 const listName = req.body.list;

 const item = new Item({
 name:itemName
  }); 
     if(listName === "Today"){
      item.save();
      res.redirect("/");
    }else{
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList){
    foundList.items.push(item);
    foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
    }
      });
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real username, pass and connection. Remove those details asap. Use something like "MyUser" "MyPass" etc

Comment: How is Atom affecting this code? If it's not directly involved then it shouldn't be tagged. Simply because it is the editor you're using isn't sufficient. Also, properly formatting your document is important on SO. See "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"

Comment: dont worry, thats not my credentials!

Comment: sure thing! will do! That was my first question on SO. Will improve. Thanks for the information.